# How i can resolve this error, it will occur when i was called a function through button

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**Error**

```
" _ctx.hello is not a function
TypeError: _ctx.hello is not a function
at onClick._cache.<computed>._cache.<computed> (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3]!./node_modules/vue-lo
ader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/components/Home.vue?vue&type=template&id=8dc7cce2:11:55)
    at callWithErrorHandling (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:285:18)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:293:17)
    at HTMLButtonElement.invoker (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-dom/dist/runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:425:82) "
```

**This is my code**

```
<template>
<div>
    <h1>Hello from Home component</h1>
    <!-- <h2>{{data}}</h2>
    <h2>{{msg}}</h2> -->
    <button v-on : click="hello('hello call')">
        Click
    </button>
</div>
    
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name:'HomeVue',
    props:{
        data: String,
        msg: String
    },
    method:{
        hello(data){
            alert(data)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The property should be methods instead of method. It's an object that contains the methods you want to define for your Vue component. You have a comment block that's not properly closed in the template section.
Solution:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Hello from Home component</h1>
    <!-- <h2>{{data}}</h2>
      <h2>{{msg}}</h2> -->
    <button v-on:click="hello('hello call')">Click</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "HomeVue",
  props: {
    data: String,
    msg: String,
  },
  methods: {
    hello(data) {
      alert(data);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```